# Функция сортировки, которая принимает методы в качестве аргумента

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Необходимо отсортировать контейнеры STL, используя разные методы доступа в качестве аргумента.

```
template<typename T>
T& getFromVectorBySquareBrackets(std::vector<T>& vector, int index)
{
  return vector[index];
}

template<typename T>
T& getFromVectorByMethodAt(std::vector<T>& vector, int index)
{
  return vector.at(index);
}

template <typename T>
typename T::value_type& getFromContainerByIterator(T& container, int index)
{
  typename T::iterator it = container.begin();
  while(index > 0)
  {
    it++;
    index--;
  }
  return *it;
}
```

Я написал функцию сортировки и хочу передать в качестве параметра методы доступа написаные выше в функцию ниже:

```
template<typename T>
void sort(T container, typename T::value_type& get(T container, int index),const char c)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < container.size(); i++)
  {
    for(int j = i+1; j < container.size()-1; j++)
    {
      if(c == 'a')
      {
        if(get(container, j) < get(container, i))
        {
          std::swap(get(container, j), get(container, i));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Но компилятор выдает ошибки в main():

```
int main{
 //something
 std::vector<int> vector = {//something};
 sort(vector, getFromVectorBySquareBrackets, 'a'); //Errors //Ошибки
 return 0;
}
```

Получаю:

> no instance of function template "sort" matches the argument list --
>   argument types are: (std::vector>,
>   unknown-type, char)

и:

> cannot determine which instance of function template
>   "getFromVectorBySquareBrackets" is intended

Также я пробовал использовать указатель на функцию (get*)(container, i), Но ничего не меняется. Имеются ли какие-либо мысли у Вас?

Comment: У нас здесь принято общаться на русском. Мне кажется, нужно перевести вопрос, либо перепостить на английский сайт: https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 8):

В шаблоне функции `sort` вы объявили обычный параметр `get` как

```
typename T::value_type& get(T container, int index)
```

Т.е. это функция<sup>1</sup>, чей первый параметр имеет тип `T`. Если рассмотреть вызов в вашем примере

```
sort(vector, getFromVectorBySquareBrackets, 'a');
```

то компилятор выполнит дедукцию шаблонного параметра `T` как `std::vector<int>`, в результате чего параметр `get` получит тип

```
int &get(std::vector<int>, int)
```

Эта функция принимает параметр типа `std::vector<int>` *по значению*. Однако ваш шаблон `getFromVectorBySquareBrackets` объявлен как

```
template<typename T>
T& getFromVectorBySquareBrackets(std::vector<T>& vector, int index)
{
  return vector[index];
}
```

Он принимает свой первый параметр *по ссылке*. Это уже является непреодолимым противоречием. Невозможно передать такую `getFromVectorBySquareBrackets` в качестве аргумента для параметра `get`: как ни специализируй шаблон `getFromVectorBySquareBrackets`, тип результата не будет соответствовать типу параметра `get`. Это именно то, на что жалуется компилятор.

Если вы измените свое объявлении шаблона `sort` на

```
template<typename T>
void sort(T container, typename T::value_type& get(T& container, int index), const char c)
```

то вышеописанная проблема будет устранена (при условии, что вы исправите и остальные очевидные синтаксические ошибки в вашем коде).

Альтернативно, если вы исправите объявление `getFromVectorBySquareBrackets` на

```
template<typename T>
T& getFromVectorBySquareBrackets(std::vector<T> vector, int index)
```

ошибка тоже исчезнет, хотя это скорее всего не совсем то, что вы хотели сделать.

---

<sup>1</sup> В списках параметров тип "функция" автоматически заменяется на тип "указатель на функцию", но в данном случае это к делу не относится.

Comment: Благодарю. Я бы пометил Ваш ответ как полезный, но похоже сломал 
 свою учетную запись, задав вопрос через гугл-аккаунт, и далее зарегестрировавшись через почту.

Comment: А зачем вы дали ответ на английском, это же ruSO

Comment: @Kromster Потому что изначально вопрос был задан на английском. Русский вариант вопроса появился уже после того, как я дал ответ.